# Targeting the Second Class of an Element and checking it against other elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to solve for $theSecondClass here.

The div with class "hr--department" has a second class of helloWorld and I want to get that class name and check it against other divs with the same class name. Then I want to do something to all the divs with that class name. Now I know I can simply target "helloWorld", but I'm actually going to need a loop here because the second class name will var per div. I could probably use IDs, but I'm still having trouble matching the class names more dynamically.

```js
var $currentDept;
//$previousDept;

$(".hr--department").click(function(){
 
 $currentDept = $theSecondClass;
 
 $($theSecondClass).each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("isOpen");
 });

});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Matching class names "dynamically" is trivial, you build a selector string (or get one passed in) and select away.

Comment: Try not using `--` use `-` instead, double hyphens denote a CSS variable like this `--cssVar`.